# Converting C code to MIPS - Iterative Factorial Function

Tags: c, mips, factorial

I'm pretty new to programming, only a few months in and was just fiddling around with some Assembly code. I ran into a problem with my MIPS code and I narrowed the problem down to my loop after printing the value of each variable. It only prints 1 as the result of any integer input. Essentially I am trying to convert this:

```
int fac(int k) {
    int i, f = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        f = f * i;
    }
    return f;
}
```

To this:

```
fac:
    move $t4, $t0 #$t0 is the input from the user and $t4 is k in the C code
    li $t1, 1 #$t1 is f in the C code, initialising it to 1
    li $t2, 1 #$t2 is i in the C code, declaring it as 1
    loop:
    ble $t2, $t4, end_loop #i<=k, end the loop
    mul $t1, $t1, $t2 #f=f*i
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    j loop
    end_loop:
```

I tested the code by putting in a bunch of print statements and was able to get $t4 and $t0, as the input but both $t1, and $t2 remain as 1 after the loop. Do I have to jump into the loop?

Comment: All of this could easily be solved with a debugger, so I'll just leave it with a hint: you've mistaken the purpose of the condition of the for-loop in your assembly-code. And a general hint: have a look at conventions on assembly-coding and specifically MIPS-assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ble $t2, $t4, end_loop #i<=k, end the loop
```

No, the second part of a C `for` statement is the condition for which you want to *continue* the loop, not end it.

What you are doing here is not even *entering* the body of the loop, which is why `$t1` and `$t2` stay the same value as you initialised them to.

You probably want to use `bgt` rather than `ble`.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I would want something like bgt $t2, $t4, end_loop? Where if i is bigger than k it ends right?

Comment: @ChristianPeterson, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition with `ble $t2, $t4, end_loop #i<=k, end the loop` will end the loop if `i<=k` but instead you want to run it as long as this condition meats. Your loop implementation doesn't even enter the loop for factorial inputs greater 1.

**Edit:** As said in the comments with the following code I've implemented a `do {...} while ();` loop which is not what the OP has asked for. However the code would work. Below the stroked text the real answer (`for` loop implementation) follows.

<strike>Remove the `end_loop:` label and jump to the `loop:` label with `ble` as last statement instead:</strike>

```
fac:
    move $t4, $t0 #$t0 is the input from the user and $t4 is k in the C code
    li $t1, 1 #$t1 is f in the C code, initialising it to 1
    li $t2, 1 #$t2 is i in the C code, declaring it as 1
    loop:
    mul $t1, $t1, $t2 #f=f*i
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    ble $t2, $t4, loop #i<=k, loop goes on if not this doesn't jump
```

To implement the for loop you've asked for you need to change the `ble` (`<=`):

```
ble $t2, $t4, end_loop #i<=k, end the loop
```

to `bgt` (`>`):

```
bgt $t2, $t4, end_loop #i>k, end the loop
```

Comment: @paxdiablo: His answer was the first when I started writing this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get it, essentially my condition right now is to continue the loop, but it ends it based on the label which it jumps to.

Comment: That's subtly different to the C `for` loop. Your loop will run at least once, it's possible for the C variant to run zero times.